# Software version number in VCS or in continuous integration server?

Tags: version-control, integration, versioning, continuous

I often discuss with my dev team how to build a good delivery workflow for our products but we are always facing the same questions concerning the versionning. During the continuous integration, who is responsible for maintaining and writing software version ? VCS or Integration Server? Or other?

Any proven strategies feedback whould be appreciated.

More deeply, our product is a bit like Microsoft Office; a suite composed of several applications linked together by some common libraries.

Until now, our integration server is maintaining the next suite version number, and is writing this version number to all apps of the suite.

Advantages:

- We immediatly know which apps are compatible together
- Easy to configure

Disadvantages:

- We don't see which app has new features / bugfix
- When fixing a previously released app, the integration server version number is not correct
- Some new apps might be compatible with older suite versions, but we don't see it